# Position of verbs in clauses

Tags: verb, word-order

When should you place the verb at the end of a clause?  I know that you're supposed to place the main verb at the end of a clause if it follows another clause; such as:

> Ich werde es nicht kaufen, weil ich es nicht will.

But what about if you're using the second clause independently, by itself.  Should it be:

> Ich werde es nicht kaufen. Weil ich es nicht will.

Or this:

> Ich werde es nicht kaufen. Weil ich will es nicht.

Comment: You can say *weil ich will es nicht* if you stress *will*. You do that if you want to emphasize that you really, really don't want it. But note that that is very colloquial and maybe even just regional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Weil" introduces a subordinate clause which does not form a complete sentence, so the second and third examples are not correct. Using subclauses as independent sentences is sometimes done in informal speech or for greater effect, but is not considered standard German.

"Denn", on the other hand, does not introduce a subordinate clause, therefore there is no reordering of the sentence structure (and you can form two independent sentences). The verb is placed at the end only in subordinate clauses.

There is an ongoing trend in colloquial speech to treat "weil" syntactically similar to "denn" as a conjunction for independent clauses. Given that trend, the third example would not be seen as incorrect in colloquial speech (but since it is far from being standard, it would easily be recognized as colloquial).

Comment: "the third example would not be seen as incorrect in colloquial speech" - I seem to remember that even then, the preferred way to write that form is: "Ich werde es nicht kaufen, weil: Ich will es nicht."

Answer (score 3):

The right word order is

> Ich werde es nicht kaufen. Weil ich es nicht will.

Dividing the subclause in a separate sentence is not grammatically correct in standard German, but it's often used in colloquial communication in order to emphasize the second part.

---

*Note:* It's interesting that if you exchange *weil* with *denn* (which means the same). The word order is different:

> Ich werde es nicht kaufen, denn ich will es nicht.

and

> Ich werde es nicht kaufen. Denn ich will es nicht.

*More about it here on [denn – weil](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907235611/http://www.deutschesprache-schweresprache.de/dennweil) and on [Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Bedeutung/kausal.html):*

> Mit kausalen (begründenden) Konjunktionen wird ein Grund, eine Ursache ausgedrückt.
>
> Zu den kausalen Konjunktionen gehören:
>
> *nebenordnend*
>
> - denn
>
> *unterordnend*
>
> - da
> - weil
> - zumal

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I knew that `Denn` had a different structure. So do you always put the main verb at the end of a clause involving `weil`? And also, a secondary question: when would you use `denn` instead of `weil`? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: yes, the word order is always the same with *weil*. There is no difference between *denn* and *weil*. You can use one instead of the other as you like. -- maybe there is a tiny tiny difference, but it's very subtle: http://www.cosmiq.de/qa/show/1470/Gebrauch-von-denn-und-weil/